# Is there an easy way to remove an app from iTunes and all iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications

We have 2 iPhones and 2 iPads synced to iTunes. It seems that to delete an app, I need to delete it from all devices individually and iTunes - i.e. 5 deletes. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which iTunes version you have installed but as of 10.2, once I deleted an app from the app list in iTunes, the app is deleted from all iOS devices the next time they're connected and synced.

Comment: But when I synch the devices it comes up with "There are purchases on this iDevice - do you want to transfer them?" So I have to make sure I haven't downloaded anything directly and then click no. Kind of annoying.